# How to check if a Queue Timer has elapsed?

Tags: c++, windows, timer, queue

I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows desktop.

Until now I thought queue timers were my perfect solution. I have queue timer being spun off a working thread. It can't pause to `SleepEx()` so Waitable Timers are not an option. I pass each of my timers an argument that is allocated on the heap and subsequently released upon completion of the timer proc.

This is my problem: If I need to cancel the timer for any reason, how do I free the argument? I can kill the timer, sure, but what if it has already elapsed, and has been queued, but not yet executed? How can I know with certainty that I can free my argument to that timer without worrying about it executing and accessing (now freed) memory?

A coworker suggested setting a flag and letting all the timers run without cancelling them. If the flag is set, free the memory and return. If not, run the timer proc as normal. This seems inefficient to me (and yeah, okay, inelegant) so I was hoping someone here had a different idea.

Comment: +1 for your friend's advice.

Comment: Hard to see the problem, DeleteTimerQueueTimer() interlocks this if you pass INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as the last argument.  When it returns, you can safely clean up.